Encountered an error executing when i creating multiple job spring batch 5
I have four job running in same time. But it shows error:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:629)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:563)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1150)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:770)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:298)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:497)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:151)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:936)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.prepareDefineBufferAndExecute(OracleStatement.java:1171)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1100)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLSelect(OracleStatement.java:1425)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1308)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3745)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3854)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1097)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
... 89 common frames omitted

Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:636)
... 106 common frames omitted

Here is my code:

My four batch schedules:
    @Slf4j
    @Configuration
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class TransactionScheduler {


      @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?")
        public void job1(){
                try {
                    JobMaker jobMaker = jobFactory.getInstance("TRANSACTION-CBL");
                    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(jobMaker.create(), new JobParameters());

                } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException |
                         JobParametersInvalidException e) {
                    log.info("{}", e.getMessage());
                }
        }



        @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?")
        public void job2(){
                try {
                    JobMaker jobMaker = jobFactory.getInstance("TRANSACTION-CBL");
                    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(jobMaker.create(), new JobParameters());
                } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException |
                         JobParametersInvalidException e) {
                    log.info("{}", e.getMessage());

                }

        }




        @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?")
        public void JOB3(){

                try {
                    JobMaker jobMaker = jobFactory.getInstance("EFT");
                    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(jobMaker.create(), new JobParameters());
                } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException |
                         JobParametersInvalidException e) {
                    log.info("{}", e.getMessage());

                }
        }



        @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?")
        public void job5(){
                try {
                    JobMaker jobMaker = jobFactory.getInstance("CBL");
                    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(jobMaker.create(), new JobParameters());

                } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
                    //log.info("{}", e.getMessage());
                }

        }


    }


My Jobfactory
        public class JobFactory {

        private JobEFT jobEFT;
        private JobCBL jobCBL;
        private JobTransactionCBL jobTransactionCBL;
        private JobTransactionEFTN jobTransactionEFTN;

        public JobMaker getInstance(String type) {
            log.info(Constants.batchTag + "{} getInstance  {}  type: "+ type);
            return switch (type) {
                case "EFT" -> jobEFT;
                case "CBL" -> jobCBL;
                case "TRANSACTION-EFTN" -> jobTransactionEFTN;
                case "TRANSACTION-CBL" -> jobTransactionCBL;
                default -> throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + type);
            };
        }
    }


MyJobs Steps Class
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    public class JobEFT implements JobMaker {

        private final TransactionSPcall transactionSPcall;
        public Job create(){
            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            return new JobBuilder("EFT-"+id, jobRepository)
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .flow(eftStep())
                    .end()
                    .build();
        }

        private Step eftStep(){
            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            id = "eftStep"+id;
            return new StepBuilder(id, jobRepository)
                    .<TransactionProjection, List<DDSITransactionDetails>> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                    .reader(new EFTReader(repository, repository, transactionSPcall))
                    .processor(batchProcessor)
                    .writer(batchWriter)
                    .build();
        }
    }





    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    public class JobCBL implements JobMaker {


        public Job create(){

            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            return new JobBuilder("CBL-"+id, jobRepository)
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .flow(cblStep())
                    .end()
                    .build();
        }

        private Step cblStep(){

            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            id = "cblStep"+id;      
            return new StepBuilder(id, jobRepository)
                    .<TransactionProjection, List<DDSITransactionDetails>> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                    .reader(new CBLReader(repository, repository, transactionSPcall))
                    .processor(batchProcessor)
                    .writer(batchWriter)
                    .build();
        }
    }






   @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    public class JobTransactionCBL implements JobMaker {


        public Job create(){
            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            return new JobBuilder("TRANSACTION-"+id, jobRepository)
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .flow(transactionStep())
                    .end()
                    .build();
        }

        private Step transactionStep(){
            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            id = "transactionStep"+id;  
            return new StepBuilder(id, jobRepository)
                    .<DDSITransactionDetails, DebitRequest> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                    .reader(new CBLTransactionReader(repository, transactionSPcall))
                    .processor(transactionProcessor)
                    .writer(transactionWriter)
                    .build();
        }
    }





    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    public class JobTransactionEFTN implements JobMaker {

        public Job create(){

            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            return new JobBuilder("TRANSACTION-"+id, jobRepository)
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .flow(transactionStep())
                    .end()
                    .build();
        }

        private Step transactionStep(){

            log.info(Constants.batchTag + "{} transactionStep ");
            return new StepBuilder("transactionStep", jobRepository)
                    .<DDSITransactionDetails, DebitRequest> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                    .reader(new EFTNTransactionReader(repository, transactionSPcall))
                    .processor(transactionProcessor)
                    .writer(transactionWriter)
                    .build();
        }
    }



My application properties:
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1633/testdb
    spring.datasource.username=test
    spring.datasource.password=test

    spring.batch.job.enabled=true
    spring.batch.job.chunk.size=10

I have set all four jobs schedule in same times.
Isn't it possible to run multiple jobs in same spring batch?

How is the datasource of the job repository initialized? Have you created the Spring Batch tables and sequences before launching your jobs?

@MahmoudBenHassine I have used below like--> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1633/testdb
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.batch.job.enabled=true
spring.batch.job.chunk.size=10

@MahmoudBenHassine I have added application.properties
